Transcribing medical notes from 1878 (query 2)
This question continues from: Transcribing medical notes from 1878
I have the following transcription queries for the following text. I think they are medicine terminology for the most part:

This is what I have managed to transcribe so far:

Ordered a mixture with xxx acid xxx. xxx ½ xxx thrice daily but requires a weak chloral of xxx night draught owing to restlessness and sleeplessness.


There is also a similar query about medicine references on page 2. I think I have managed to work it out (with a bit of help from ChatGPT). But still a couple of phrases I am not sure of:

This is what I have managed to transcribe so far:

Wild and furious, and the last two days suffering from meningitis – her disordered brain and membrane having been attacked by the poison of the disease. A nurse is now obliged to remain with her, night and day. Cooling lotions applied to the head and the hair cut off. To take Calomel and Pulv Ipecac Co tonight and morning, and a mixture with Ether Chlor, xxx, Sig Ammonia Acid, Sig Morph Acid and 12 quantities a dose every 3 or 4 hours.

I am not convinced that it reads 12 quantities.

ChatGPT

Pulv Ipecac Co is likely an abbreviation for "Pulvis Ipecacuanhae Compositus", which translates to Compound Ipecac Powder. This was a common medicinal powder used in the past.

Ether Chlor likely refers to Chloroform Ether, a historical chemical compound often used in medicine. It is a combination of chloroform (CHCl₃) and ethyl ether (C₂H₅OC₂H₅), both of which were used as anesthetics or sedatives in the 19th and early 20th centuries.

Sig Ammonia Acid is likely an abbreviation or historical term for "Spirit of Ammonia" (also known as Ammonia Water or Aqua Ammoniae), which is a solution of ammonia in water. It's a strong alkaline compound that was commonly used in medical treatments in the past, particularly for respiratory issues or as a mild stimulant.

Sig Morph Acid is likely an abbreviation for "Syrup of Morphine Acid" or could refer to morphine sulfate combined with an acid, possibly citric acid or another acidic compound.


